# Clearing apcu with a wild card

Tags: php, symfony, apc

Is it possible to clear apcu cache using a wild card?

For instance I may have a bunch of cache keys:

products_fooandbars
product_1_foo

users_fooandbars
user_1_foo
user_1_bar

user_2_foo
user_2_bar

Is there a way to clear everything that user 1 has like this
user_1_* or clear all the user's like this  user_*

I'm using Symfony with the doctrine apc cache classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP refers to [*APCu*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apcu.php) not *APC*.
There isn't much difference in function names, etc, but it's best for anyone to make clear that **APC** is the old version, and **APCu** is the new one, with a much better implementation.

Old APC implements both opcode cache and user object cache. APCu only implements user object cache. For opcode cache you use something else, like Zend OPcache.
That said, here's an updated version from @Evgenly's:

```
// delete all keys beginning with a regex match
foreach(new APCUIterator('/^MY_KEY/') as $apcu_cache){
    echo 'key: ' . $apcu_cache['key'] . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'val: ' . $apcu_cache['value'];
    apcu_delete($apcu_cache['key']); 
}
```

The foreach is illustrative, you can also do:

```
apcu_delete(new APCUIterator('/^MY_KEY/'));
```

Comment: Yep thats what I needed.  same approach to APC really.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I believe you should try as it was described http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-delete.php#101794

```
// delete all keys beginning with a regex match on MY_APC_TESTA
$toDelete = new APCIterator('user', '/^MY_KEY/', APC_ITER_VALUE);

var_dump( apc_delete($toDelete) );
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed